# Query Parameter Not Showing the Correct Parameters

Tags: angular

When I add items to the query parameters, it shows an object in the URL. How can I get it to show the items?

This is the HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="submitForm" (ngSubmit)="checkOut(items)">
<input type="submit" value="Check Out">
</form>
```

This is the component:

```
public checkOut(items: any)  {
this.router.navigate(['check-out'], { queryParams: { items: this.items } });
}
```

This is what the URL looks like:

http://localhost:4200/check-out?items=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&items=%5Bobject%20Object%5D

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do some extra works for it to show in the URL, maybe try to convert it to JSON before passing it to queryParams.
Try this:

```
public checkOut(items: any)  {
  this.router.navigate(['check-out'], { queryParams: { items: JSON.stringify(this.items) } });
}
```

If you want to retrieve the object you can parse it using

```
JSON.parse(yourStringifiedObject)
```